# Merge object in node

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of object like this. Can you show me the way how to merge ojbect with id = 1 to one big object and all categories with id=1 to this object. so, can anyone help me, i really need your help. Thanks a lot

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Hello",          
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "nameVI": "Music"              
            }         
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Hello", 
            "category": {
                "id": 2,
                "nameVI": "Family"                
            }           
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Hello", 
            "category": {
                "id": 3,                
                "nameEN": "Sensory"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "good bye",            
            "category": {
                "id": 1,               
                "nameEN": "Music"
            }
        },
        {
             "id": 2,
            "title": "good bye",     
            "category": {
                "id": 2,                
                "nameEN": "Family"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "good bye",     
            "category": {
                "id": 3,              
                "nameEN": "Sensory"
            }
       }]
```

Comment: What is the expected output and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you want exactly. Here is a simple way to chose default values(`id` and `title`) and merge `categories`.

```
const mergeObj = (id, obj) => {
    const newObj = {};
    obj.forEach((el) => {
        if (el.id === id) {
            if (!newObj.id) {
                newObj.id = el.id;
                newObj.title = el.title;
                newObj.categories = [];
            }
            newObj.categories.push(el.category);
        }
    });
    return newObj;
};
```